# How to get routing table in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

How can I get the routing tables in command line? On a normal unix machine I can use

```
[user@server ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp5s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 enp5s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 enp5s0
```

On my macbook, this does not work

```
[user@macbook ~]# > route -n
usage: route [-dnqtv] command [[modifiers] args]
```

What be the equivilent command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try

```
netstat -r
```

Note that this will resolve the names of the gateways if possible. This takes some time. If you don't need this, run

```
netstat -rn
```

Comment: You might be intersted in the `netstat -nr -f inet` command if interested in getting **only the IPv4** routes and remove the IPv6 pollution.